# Como retorno un BadRequest en GET que retorna una lista Net Core 6

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Como retorno un BadRequest en una para una función que retorna un IEnumerable.

En la siguiente función retorno una lista de productos con entre un valor máximo y mínimo, pero quiero asegurarme que eses valores serán positivos lo cual usare el IF de la función para asegurarme, en caso de que alguno sea negativo quiero retornar un BadRequest pero obviamente controlador no me deja por eso quiero alguna forma de retornarlo, muchas gracias de antemano

```
[HttpGet]
        [Route("api/listaEntrePrecios")]
        public async Task<IEnumerable<Producto>> listaEntrePrecios(int minimo , int maximo)
        {

            if (maximo <0 || minimo<0)
            {

                return BadRequest();
                
            }

            var parameters = new[]
            {
                new SqlParameter("@Minimo",minimo),
                new SqlParameter("@Maximo",maximo)
            };

            var lista =await context.productos.FromSqlRaw("EXECUTE listaProductoPrecio @Minimo, @Maximo", parameters).ToListAsync();


            return lista;
        }
```

Comment: vas a tener que retornar o un error, o un IActionResult...

Comment: creo que eso es lo que tendre que  hacer